# Is there a word that means "not fitting my preferred version of reality"?

Tags: single-word-requests

For example, suppose there's a nice guy I don't know very well. He, through a series of unfortunate events, marries an abusive cheating skank. This does not hurt my feelings, as I am not emotionally invested in the well-being of this particular nice guy. But in my preferred version of the universe, nice guys would not have to deal with such calamity.

What word conveys, rather dispassionately, that good people should have good things happen to them, and a dislike for this being untrue?

Comment: Not a single word, but the phrase *in the best of all possible worlds ...* is often seen.

Comment: *Not my cup of tea.*

Comment: Meanwhile, in a parallel universe...

Comment: Using it in your context would probably get blasted as faux/situational irony, like Alanis got blasted, but I think that noting the irony of a situation implies that you wanted/had at least expected a different outcome:“I find it [ironic that bad things](https://books.google.com/books?id=YgyoqSrgQXAC&pg=PA153&lpg=PA153&dq=%22ironic+that+bad+things%22&source=bl&ots=o5set2qz-H&sig=iurA30JWYlfPKY0PB0B6PKyoBHA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjTusfEkrbKAhUUHmMKHai1DHYQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=%22ironic%20that%20bad%20things%22&f=false) do sometimes happen to nice people//how nice guys do sometimes finish last.”

Comment: Life isn't fair.

Comment: There is the concept of "cognitive dissonance", which means that some fact or bit of knowledge that you are forced to confront contradicts your preconceptions, causing angst.  But I'm not sure that this suits your situation.

Comment: It's an *unjust* situation, so an *injustice*.  *Calamitous* / *calamity* are also good.

Answer (score 5):

[**ideal**](https://www.google.co.kr/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=ideal%20synonym)

> adjective
>
> 1. satisfying one's conception of what is perfect; most suitable.
> 2. existing only in the imagination; desirable or perfect but not likely to become a reality.

I would say:

> "*Ideally* (in my preferred version of the universe), nice guys shouldn't have to deal with such a calamity."

Answer (score 1):

A [paradigm](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/paradigm) is defined as "an example serving as a model" and there are several synonyms for the word, but the related [thesaurus site](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/paradigm) isn't showing any antonyms. Thus, you might create one with a prefix, such as **anti-paradigm**. If you wanted an adjective, it would be **anti-paradigmatic**.

Comment: "Paradigm shift" might be applicable to Opie's situation.

Comment: @HotLicks Sure. I was looking for a one-word answer that could be defined (per the subject line) as "not fitting my preferred version of reality".

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear exactly how you want to use the word or phrase, but it sounds like you are being an **idealist** or **utopianist**. Seeing your friend's situation has **disillusioned** you, shattering your **idealism**/**utopianism**. Or maybe it hasn't shattered them, because you are a **denialist** who is in **denial** about his friend's troubles and refuses to accept the difference between your preferred version of reality and the actual reality.

Another idea that comes to mind is the rhetorical trope "**In an ideal world, [X]. In the world we actually live in, [Y]**," which can be used in the context of a conversation about your feelings. I used this pattern in a recent Academia.SE post, which I seem to remember was somewhat successful, but don't remember the details.

Comment: Sounds like the guy isn't the OP's friend, just a person he knows